# Child attr displaying for parent pseudo

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get the attribute of the child element in the parent's pseudo element.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <pre>
     <code class="foo" data-lang="bar">
      ....
     </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

What i need is **.parent::after** have `attr(data-lang)` from **.foo** as content

thank you

Comment: no it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***It's not possible to do this*** as CSS by nature (*and name*) cascades. So the child elements data attribute is out of scope for the parent elements pseudo element to use.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr):

> The attr() CSS function is used to retrieve the value of an attribute of the selected element and use it in the style sheet. It can also be used on pseudo-elements, in which case the value of the attribute on the pseudo-element's originating element is returned.

It depends what you're after exactly with the value of the data attribute, but you can still style things with the child element but it depends on your use case for it. If you can, move the data attribute up to the parent (*if that's possible to do here*).

Comment: "So the child elements data attribute is out of scope for the parent elements pseudo element to use." That's not due to cascading. It just is.